# rgb to hex return wrong value when giving rgb(1,2,3) in c

Tags: c

i am still a beginner with c and am writing a converter RGB to HEX for "code wars" challenge  which would for e.g return
`010203` when i give `rgb(1,2,3)` but it returns `030303`
i have checked my converting logic  and its correct (i guess) 
this is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* convert(int num){
    int rem;
    char deg[17]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    static char ret[3];
    rem=num%16;
    num=num/16;
    ret[0]=deg[num];
    ret[1]=deg[rem];
    return ret;
}

int rgb(int r, int g, int b, char *output)
{
    snprintf(output,sizeof(output),"%s%s%s",convert(r),convert(g),convert(b));
    return 0; 
}
```

i have tried also replacing `snpritf` by `strcat`
but then insted of returning `00FF7D` it return 37D when giving `rgb(0,255,125)`
this is how replaced `snpritf` by `strcat`:

```
  strcat(output,convert(r));
  strcat(output,convert(g));
  strcat(output,convert(b));
```

i am really confused any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use `strcpy()` for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you return the address of a `static` array of char, your three calls to `convert()` all return the same address.

Each call overwrites the array then replaces what was done by the previous calls.

You should create three distinct arrays in `rgb()` and pass one of each as a parameter to each of the calls to `convert()`.

Another solution is to simplify a bit as below.
Because we know that `convert()` must write two characters, simple pointer arithmetic with step 2 can do the trick.
By the way, don't forget the string termination (`\0`) in `convert()` (with your static array it was implicit, but now you have to explicitly initialise with 0).

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>

void
convert(int num,
        char *result)
{
  const char *deg="0123456789ABCDEF";
  result[0]=deg[num/16];
  result[1]=deg[num%16];
  result[2]='\0';
}

int
rgb(int r, int g, int b,
    char *output, size_t capacity)
{
  if(capacity<7)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  convert(r, output+0);
  convert(g, output+2);
  convert(b, output+4);
  return 0; 
}

int
main(void)
{
  char txt[20];
  rgb(1, 2, 3, txt, sizeof(txt));
  printf("%s\n", txt);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt was almost right, but you need to use `strcpy()` for the first string, unless `output` is initialized to an empty string.

```
void rgb(int r, int g, int b, char *output)
{
    strcpy(output,convert(r));
    strcat(output,convert(g));
    strcat(output,convert(b));
    return; 
}
```